# how to insert a query within a class?

Tags: php, class, pdo

I am working on a class where I want to check if everything is filled in and if everything is filled in then insert into the database, but I am stuck on how I can insert within my class so I hope you guys could help me. I never got any errors of this problem.

Here is the code:

```
<?php


class clsCatCheck
{

    private $catName;

    public function __construct($catName)
    {
        $this->setCatName($catName);
    }

    public function setCatName($catName)
    {
        $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname', "username", "password");

            $select = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM category');
            $row = $select->fetch();

            if (isset($_POST['addCat'])) {
                if (empty($_POST['catName'])) {
                    throw new Exception('Geen categorienaam is ingevuld<br />');
                }
                //if (strlen($_POST['catName'] <= 4)) {
                  //  throw new Exception('De categorienaam moet minimaal 4 letters of langer zijn<br />');
                //}
                if ($_POST['catName'] == $row[1]) {
                    throw new Exception('Deze categorienaam bestaat al<br />');
                }
            }
            else {
                $query = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO category (catName) VALUES (:catName = catName)");
                $query->bindParam(':catName', $_POST['catName'] ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->execute();
            }

        $this->catName = $catName;
    }

    public function getCatName()
    {
        return $this->catName;
    }
}
```

Already thanks for helping.
If you want more code from me just ask.

Comment: `VALUES (:catName = catName)` that should read as `VALUES (:catName)` and using exceptions would have triggered a syntax error. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - what you're using now, is UPDATE syntax, not INSERT.

Comment: Well I tried but it didn't seem to work

Comment: ah well that guy below; posted an answer so ask him. I'll have to stay out of this loop.

Comment: so, you're not asking the other guy about his answer and why it's not working. Are you waiting on another answer, if not a *magic* answer?

Comment: Sorry for not reacting but I was busy with my group and forgot about my question on stack

Comment: well that guy's answer below is getting more upvotes to a question that didn't solve it, so again... ask him. He needs to work for those points. ;-) I can't do the work for him. If he can't help you, he should delete the answer.

Comment: Okay thx for the tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not binding parameters correctly.

Corrected code:

```
$query = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO category (catName) VALUES (:catName)");
$query->bindParam(':catName', $_POST['catName'] ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: [yeah, I said that 6 mins. prior to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840118/how-to-insert-a-query-within-a-class#comment61250026_36840118). Maybe the OP only answers to answers and not comments. I do believe mine was a better explanation.

Comment: Yes @Fred-ii-, you have explained definitely well. No doubts. But, to my little knowledge, I found some error there. Therefore, I posted answer.

Comment: @Pupil thx for your answer but it isn't working. I don't why it isn't working.